# Django queryset StringAgg on arrayfield

Tags: django, django-orm, string-aggregation, string-agg

I have some data which includes sizes, much like the model below.

```
class Product(models.Model):
    width = models.CharField()
    height = models.CharField()
    length = models.CharField()
```

Through annotation we have a field called at_size which produces data like:

- [None, None, None]
- ['200', '000', '210']
- ['180', None, None]

This was accomplished like so (thanks to: )https://stackoverflow.com/a/70266320/5731101:

```
    class Array(Func):
        template = '%(function)s[%(expressions)s]'
        function = 'ARRAY'

    out_format = ArrayField(CharField(max_length=200))

    annotated_qs = Product.objects.all().annotate(
        at_size=Array(F('width'), F('height'), F('length'), 
            output_field=out_format)
    )
```

I'm trying to get this to convert into:

- ''
- '200 x 000 x 210'
- '180'

In code, this could a bit like `' x '.join([i for i in data if i])`.  But as I need to accomplish this with database functions it's a bit more challenging.

I've been playing with StringAgg, but I keep getting:

`HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.`

It looks like I need to make sure the None values are excluded from the initial Array-func to begin with. But I'm not sure where to get started here.
How can I accomplish this?

Comment: What database do you use?

Comment: I'm using Postgres

Comment: What about the `Concat` db function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out the problem was two-fold.

1. Cleaning out the Null values could be done through using array_remove
2. glueing the strings with a delimiter through StringAgg only works if the input are strings.  But since we use an array, that wasn't the way to go.  Instead use array_to_string

The final result looks like:

```
    class Array(Func):
        # https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/functions-array.html
        template = '%(function)s[%(expressions)s]'
        function = 'ARRAY'

    class ArrayRemove(Func):
        # https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/functions-array.html
        function = 'array_remove'

    class ArrayToString(Func):
        # https://stackoverflow.com/a/57873772/5731101
        function = 'array_to_string'

    out_format = ArrayField(CharField(max_length=200))

    annotated_qs = annotated_qs.annotate(
        at_size=ArrayToString(
            ArrayRemove(
                Array(F('width'), F('height'), F('length'), output_field=out_format),
                None, # Remove None values from the Array with ArrayRemove                
            ),
            Value(" x "),  # Delimiter.
            Value(''),  # If there are null-values, replace with... (fallback)
            output_field=CharField(max_length=200),
        )
    )
```

this produces the desired format:

```
for product in annotated_qs:
    print(product.at_size)

180 x 000 x 200
180 x 026 x 200
180 x 7 x 200
180 x 000 x 200
200 x 000 x 220
180 x 000 x 200
175 x 230 x 033
160 x 000 x 200

60 x 220
```

Comment: Ahhhhh. Very nice :) well done!

Comment: ty :). Was quite the search, but turned out to stare me right in the face...Note to self: read the docs...

Answer (score 0):

```
Product.objects.annotate(display_format=Concat(F('width'), '×', F('height'), '×', F('length')))
```

Should do the trick no?

No need to over complicate this, let's keep it nice and simple and use the database to concatenate the 3 strings and separate them with the multiplication symbol (obviously replace if you prefer another character).

Take a look at the docs over here:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/database-functions/#concat

Comment: Unfortunately that would produce " x x x" when there are all null values.

Comment: Ok. Let me revise my answer slightly as I'm sure there's a way :)

Comment: So far, I've managed to exclude the null-values by using array_remove.  But still getting the same error on StringAgg even though the array only contain strings.